# XML helper codeigniter

Tags: xml, codeigniter, helper

How to use xml helper in  codeigniter ?
In the Code Igniter user guide, there is no example and also what ? why ? how ? and when this is used? Is to read or to write an xml file?? please help

Comment: You can just use htmlspecialchars() to escape for XML: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score 1):

The CodeIgniter helper is only used to convert a string so that it does't contain characters that are "reserved" by converting the characters to entities.

- Ampersands: & to `&amp;`
- Less then and greater than characters: < > to `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively
- Single and double quotes: '  " to `&apos;` and `&quot;` respectively
- Dashes: - to `&dash;`

There are very short example at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/xml_helper.html.

You'd want to use if it you were trying to, for example, generate an RSS feed. Your controller would load the helper and the view would use the `xml_convert` function provided by the helper when echoing the data.

**Example:**

```
<item>
  <title><?php echo xml_convert($post->title); ?></title>
</item>
```

Comment: Sorry i dint get you properly. Where do we load the xml file ?

Comment: What does $post->title give me ?  can u give me a detailed explanation.

Comment: @Rahul - `$post->title` is just an example and it doesn't apply to you. You don't "get" an XML file, you "make" one. The `xml_convert` doesn't read of make XML files. It prepares the string that goes inside a tag so that it doesn't contain "reserved" characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xml helper while inserting items to db:

```
class Parser_model extends CI_Model {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('xml');
    }
    function insert_items($directory) {
           $fields_data = array(
                "server_name" => xml_convert($item->server_name),
                "listen_url" => xml_convert($item->listen_url),
           );
           $this->db->insert($table_name,$fields_data);
    }
}
```

the inserted data will be:

```
**server_name**           |     **listen_url**
----------------------------------------
radio&#45;vitalist    | http://radionomy.com/Absolute&#45;VIBEZ&#45;
```

It converted some reserved characters to html entities so controls future errors.
And also u can use while displaying the items.